# C code decomposer

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering whether there exists a program to break a c source code down to a lower level code by substituting all loops and function calls by goto statement. Thus, it would reduce a code to variable declaration/heap allocation, if statement, goto statement and logic/arithmetic functions.

I think such program would be useful for designing a virtual machine to interpret C code.

Example:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++){
    printf("Hello");
}
```

would become

```
int a = 0;
if(!(a<100)){
    goto endForLoopOne;
}
forLoopOne:
    printf("Hello");
    if(a<100){
        a++;
        goto forLoopOne;
    }
endForLoopOne:
```

Comment: Actually I think such a transformer would make it **harder** to implement C code.  In my beginning compiler class it was pretty easy to compile _for_ statements and _if_ statements.  _goto_ statements are harder because in general they can jump anywhere in a function, not well defined places like the end of an _if_ block.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` and `clang` (or probably many other compilers) allows you to get assembly output from c source.
In gcc -S flag will produce a `.s` file.

```
gcc -S <your c source>
```

The syntax of assembly will be AT&T though.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand the functionality you are asking about is somewhat implemented in compiler construction. The original high level code is transformed to  intermediate 3 address code. What i think a simple parser/compiler can be written that can do that. I wrote one such program for assignment in compiler design course this month.It was written in c using flex(lexical analyser) and bison(yacc).